# ConvertAPI convertapi-python failing with error to convert PDF_PPT input file to PPTX output file

Tags: file-conversion

I followed the instructions for this API conversion service, but get an error that is not covered in their documentation.  Below is just a test to see if I can get it working for 1 PDF file.   I have over 100 to convert, so I would rather use a proven service, rather than create my own converter.

Here's the code I used:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
''' Spyder Editor '''

import convertapi

path = r'C:\conversion_test' 

filename = r'10-cleaning-data-in-python-folder_4-cleaning-data-for-analysis-folder_ch4_slides'

path_and_filename = path + filename 

convertapi.api_secret = 'LoDZP1klb1farkdh'
convertapi.convert('pptx', {'File': path_and_filename }, from_format = 'pdf').save_files(path)
```

The error I am getting is:  AttributeError: 'ApiError' object has no attribute 'message'

Here's the full stack trace.

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\convertapi\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3284, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\convertapi\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2023, in showtraceback
    self._showtraceback(etype, value, stb)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\convertapi\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 546, in _showtraceback
    u'evalue' : py3compat.safe_unicode(evalue),

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\convertapi\lib\site-packages\ipython_genutils\py3compat.py", line 65, in safe_unicode
    return unicode_type(e)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\convertapi\lib\site-packages\convertapi\exceptions.py", line 14, in **str**
    message = "%s Code: %s. %s" % (self.message, self.code, self.invalid_parameters)

AttributeError: 'ApiError' object has no attribute 'message'

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Comment: That was a trial account with the service `convertapi' anyway and this was so long ago that the convertapi.secret should have expired by now.  I didn't like the service because it charged by the number of conversions.  convertapi is not a free toolkit that could be downloaded and installed.  `convertapi' essentially requires pay-per-use.  I ended up downloading a free (no cost) Python utility to drive Acrobat to convert the files in bulk.